# Display Upcoming Dates By This Week, Next Week and Next Month on a separate sheet

Tags: google-sheets, filter, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

I am new to google sheets. I have a spreadsheet with all my data and im trying to build a dashboard for easy digestion for my team. Part of the data is keeping track of our filming dates for each client. From shoot one up to shoot 4, so 4 columns of dates. What I want to do is have any of those dates that fall into "This Week" to be displayed in a column on another sheet titled the same thing. Followed by a column with "Next Week" and "Next Month" so that I can see at a glance all the upcoming shoot days. Quite simply I have no idea how to do this.

Another aspect of it is that I also want the first 2 columns of the data sheet to display next to the date in the dashboard sheet as well as this holds the client name and project name. The first 2 columns being `'2022'!A3:B` and the list of dates being `'2022'!S3:V`.

Any help or guidance will be massively appreciated!

I have tried using an Array Formula and Filter formula but am struggling to know what to search to find the answer I need so have come on here for some help.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Hi @player0, not a problem. I have made a copy and removed all personal information. I have displayed how I want the final version to look on the first sheet. I want the client name and project name to copy not only the text but the conditional formatting so I can keep track of if its an enquiry or active. Let me know if you need further details. I appreciate any and all help!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_xIl8Uns1RQH11oDiEtvRuz_9ZeGO_rC6qNuf5MHwqI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this week:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF('2022'!S3:V="",,'2022'!A3:A&"×"&'2022'!B3:B&"×"&TEXT('2022'!S3:V, 
 "dd/mm/yy\×dddd")&"×"&WEEKNUM('2022'!S3:V, 2)&"×"&'2022'!C3:C)), "×"), 
 "where Col6 matches 'ACTIVE|ENQUIRY' 
    and Col5 = "&WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 2)), 9^9, 4))
```

next week:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF('2022'!S3:V="",,'2022'!A3:A&"×"&'2022'!B3:B&"×"&TEXT('2022'!S3:V, 
 "dd/mm/yy\×dddd")&"×"&WEEKNUM('2022'!S3:V, 2)&"×"&'2022'!C3:C)), "×"), 
 "where Col6 matches 'ACTIVE|ENQUIRY' 
    and Col5 = "&IF(WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 2)+1>WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 12, 31), 2), 1, 
 WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 2)+1)), 9^9, 4))
```

next month:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF('2022'!S3:V="",,'2022'!A3:A&"×"&'2022'!B3:B&"×"&TEXT('2022'!S3:V, 
 "dd/mm/yy\×dddd")&"×"&MONTH('2022'!S3:V)&"×"&'2022'!C3:C)), "×"), 
 "where Col6 matches 'ACTIVE|ENQUIRY' 
    and Col5 = "&MONTH(EOMONTH(TODAY(), 1))), 9^9, 4))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HAbVarr7Os0e54AKbUpz2Mf5Z4yLtUqJLqYGQATSWsY/edit#gid=1095862101)